# Variant Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Set $\mathbb{D}=D_1(0)$. Let $f$ & $g$ holomorphic functions in a neighborhood of the disc $\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(z)\not=0$ and $\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}\notin(-\infty,0]$ for all $z\in\partial\mathbb{D}$. Then $f$ & $g$ have the same zeros (multiplicity counting) on $\mathbb{D}$

Comment: Easily follows from the symmetric form where the hypothesis is $|f - g| < |f| + |g|$ on $\partial \mathbb D$.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle h(z)=\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}$ and $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ , $t\in [0,2\pi]$

$Z_h=Z_g$ , $P_h=Z_f$ (we can assume that $f$ and $g$ have no common zeros)

The argument principle states that

$\displaystyle Z_h-P_h=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{h'(t)}{h(t)}dt=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{h\circ \gamma}\frac{1}{w}dw=0$ , $\displaystyle\frac{1}{w}$ has primitive on $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$

Therefore $Z_f=Z_g$ on $B(0,1)$.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ have common zeros? I lost information about the zeros of $h$.

Comment: as I can to ensure that it is valid?

Comment: @Donyarley For example $ \frac{g(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{(z-1)^5 g_1(z)}{(z-1)^3f_1(z)}=\frac{(z-1)^2g_1(z)}{f_1(z)}=\frac{G(z)}{F(z)}$ where $F$ and $G$ have no common zeros, $f_1$ and $g_1$ are zero-free functions (note that $f$ and $g$ have finite zeros inside the disk otherwise would be identically zero by Identity Principle).

Therefore $f$ and $g$ have $3$ common zeros ,  $Z_f=Z_F+3$ , $Z_g=Z_G+3$ and $Z_F=Z_G$ by the previous case, hence $Z_f=Z_g$ on $B(0,1)$.